# Converting GeoJson/Shp to Iso-xml (ISOBUS ISO 11783-10)

Tags: shapefile, geojson, xml

How do I convert some geojson/shp files to ISOBUS iso-xml files, ISO 11783-10?

I am having a hard time finding any information.

Comment: Please clarify. It is a big standard and expensive to acquire "Tractors and machinery for agriculture and forestry -- Serial control and communications data network -- Part 10: Task controller and management information system data interchange". I guess that few people here have an access to the standard.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up buying the standard and writing an implementation in Golang.