# Converting GeoJSON to ISOXML ISOBUS ISO 11783-10

Tags: geojson, xml

**How do I convert some GeoJSON files to ISOXML files (ISO 11783-10)?**

I found several questions on this topic:

- [Converting GeoJson/Shp to Iso-xml (ISOBUS ISO 11783-10)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/270339/159900)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/48623806/13070285

I am trying to contact the author of these questions directly to find out more details.

But maybe someone has experience converting files between these formats.

Especially using the ISOXML plugin for ADAPT framework:

- https://github.com/ADAPT/ISOv4Plugin
- https://github.com/ADAPT/ADAPT

I try to import an ISOXML file into an ADAPT Data Model using the ISOXML plugin, understand the data structure inside the model and try to export back to the ISOXML format.

https://github.com/ADAPT/ISOv4Plugin/blob/bc5ff975338abe85963f882945a7ed61e7ac470d/ISOv4Plugin/Plugin.cs#L28-L42

I am stuck on the fact that I can’t understand if I can export the model back to ISOXML file. I asked these questions directly to the developers on GitHub and by email, but haven't received an answer yet.

Maybe someone was dealing with the ISOXML format or tried to do the same with the ISOXML plugin for the ADAPT framework.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: If the format is properly specified, then it shouldn't be an issue, for you to write a file that can be read.

Answer (score 1):

The standard (part 10) can be bought here:
https://www.iso.org/standard/61581.html

Me and two fellow workers created a geo tools data store to parse ISOXML files and show them on a map:
https://github.com/ManuelB/geoserver-iso-11783-part-10

This also includes an ISOXML generator that shows how to create an XML file and a timelog:
https://github.com/ManuelB/geo-tools-iso-11783-part-10/blob/main/src/test/java/de/incentergy/iso11783/part10/geotools/ISOXMLGenerator.java

So to generate this from GeoJSON you have to convert the GeoJSON to the corresponding ISOXML structures e.g. Partfield (PFD).

Further there is also the tool NEXT Wayline Converter:
https://www.fusesmartfarming.com/products/next-wayline-converter-tool/

That tool can generate ISOXML from multiple source at the moment GeoJSON is not supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

ADAPT Framework provides ability to convert between different data types using plugins.

There are open source plugins for both formats:

- [GeoJSONPlugin](https://github.com/ADAPT/GeoJSONPlugin)
- [ISOv4Plugin](https://github.com/ADAPT/ISOv4Plugin)

Also, you can try [ADAPT-CLI](https://github.com/ADAPT/ADAPT-CLI) if your goal is only converting from one format to another.